# VBA - Add different ships on the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty new to VBA. I am trying to create a simple battleship game. When a user is clicking on the game area, I would like to create a pop-up that allows me to insert different elements.

Example:

```
Ship 1 (length 2 columns & colour "red")
Ship 2 (length 3 columns & colour "blue")
Ship 3 (length 4 columns & colour "black")
Ship 4 (length 5 columns & colour "green")
```

What would be the best way to achieve this (userform or CommandButton clicks)? Do you have any examples?

That's what I have written so far:

**Worksheet area**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim chemin1 As Object
Set chemin1 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
With chemin1
    .Clear
    .Range("A1:J10").Interior.ColorIndex = 36
With Range("A1:J10").Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Range("A1:J10").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Range("A1:J10").Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Range("A1:J10").Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Range("A1:J10").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    End With

End Sub
```

**Action to add the ships in the worksheet**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim LB_2 As Variant, LB_3, LB_4 As Variant, LB_5 As Variant
Dim LB_6 As Variant
Set chemin1 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
With chemin1
LB_2 = TB_1.variant
.Range("TB_1").Interior.ColorIndex = 22
LB_3 = TB_2.variant
.Range("TB_2").Interior.ColorIndex = 22
LB_4 = TB_3.variant
.Range("TB_3").Interior.ColorIndex = 22
LB_5 = TB_4.variant
.Range("TB_4").Interior.ColorIndex = 22
LB_6 = TB_5.variant
.Range("TB_5").Interior.ColorIndex = 22
End With

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub
```

Comment: Pick whichever method you prefer, try writing some code, then post back with your code if you run into problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you asked for but maybe this van get you going. For this code you will need to place a simple button somewhere and press it if you selected the cell you want to place your ship.

```
Option Explicit
Sub battleship()
Dim length As Integer
Dim color As String
    length = InputBox("Please give the length of your ship")
    color = InputBox("Please give the color of your ship")
    If color = "red" Then
        Do While length > 0
            length = length - 1
            ActiveCell.Interior.color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    ElseIf color = "green" Then
        Do While length > 0
            length = length - 1
            ActiveCell.Interior.color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

This is an example that only works if you enter green or red. I think you can do the others by your own.

I hope this helped :)

Comment: I know its totally diffrent but I hope this will help you.